# Set display of div by using the data-target attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I got a question regarding setting the display of a div with the use of the `data-target` attribute. I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="page page-current" id="home">
PAGE 1
  <a href="#" class="next" data-target="#about">Go to about</a>
</div>

<div class="page page-section" id="about">
PAGE 2
  <a href="#" class="next" data-target="#portfolio">Go to portfolio</a>
</div>

<div class="page page-section" id="portfolio">
  PAGE 3
</div>
```

As can seen above, the div's that contain the class: `page-section` are initial hidden by CSS using: `display:none`. Now I managed to create a generic JS code that checks which div should be made visible:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).data("target");
  $(target).addClass("page-current");  
})
```

The problem with this is that it adds to the second div the class: `page-current` but the first div also still contains this class.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction how I could solve this is in a generic way so that only one div at the time can contain the class: `page-current`

I have created a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nw3m7g2r/) of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do what you require you need to remove the `page-current` from the current page, and add it to the new element, while removing `page-section` from the new element and adding it back on to the old.

You can do this by using the `toggleClass()` method, like this:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $('.page-current').add(target).toggleClass('page-current page-section');
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nw3m7g2r/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your clean and helpful answer. That was what I am looking for.